# Iterate through the foreach loop array only after the ajax request is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, foreach

I'd like to iterate next time **only** after the ajax request is successful.

You can clearly see what's going on here on the dev console. There is a `console.log(...);` function inside the `foreach` loop. And this condition should be always true. I can achieve this result using `async: false` in both of these AJAX request, however, it blocks UI.

In my particular situation, where it's not a normal webpage, just a single project, I could do this, however, I don't want to use it. I need other ideas.

`Console.log(....);` function returns different values different times but It should always be the same value in the left, and in the right side.

For example: `ESL_SC2 == habathcx` - WRONG, `ESL_SC2 == ESL_SC2` - CORRECT.

---

Open the console to see the result. Only look at the JS part.

```js
$(function() {
  $("html").removeClass("no-js");
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest(),
    users = [
      "ESL_SC2",
      "OgamingSC2",
      "cretetion",
      "freecodecamp",
      "storbeck",
      "habathcx",
      "RobotCaleb",
      "noobs2ninjas",
      "mhayia"
    ],
    index,
    ajaxDone,
    userResults = [],
    $search = $("#search"),
    keyCode,
    request;

  var getUserResults = function(callback) {
    index = 0;
    users.forEach(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + e,
        beforeSend: function() {
          ajaxDone = false;
        },
        success: function(d) {

          if (d.display_name !== undefined) {
            userResults[index] = {
              name: d.display_name
            };
            console.log(users[index] + " == " + e);
          }

          index++;

          if (index == users.length) {
            callback();
          }

          ajaxDone = true;
        },
        error: function() {
          alert(
            "AJAX Request failed. Please try again or contact using email n3olukas@gmail.com."
          );
        },
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });
  };

  getUserResults(function() {
    index = 0;
    users.forEach(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + e,
        success: function(d) {
          if (d.stream !== null) {
            userResults[index].status = d.stream.channel !== undefined ? 'Online' : '';
            userResults[index].title = d.stream.channel !== undefined ? d.stream.channel.status != undefined ? d.stream.channel.status : '' : '';
            userResults[index].url = d.stream.channel !== undefined ? d.stream.channel.url !== undefined ? d.stream.channel.url : '' : '';
          }

          if (userResults[index].name) {
            $('#tabs-1 table').append('<tr><td>' + userResults[index].name + '</td><td>' + (userResults[index].status ?
              'Online' : 'Offline') + '</td><td>' + (userResults[index].title ?
              userResults[index].title : '') + '</td></tr>');
          }

          index++;

          $("body").addClass("loaded");
        },
        error: function() {
          alert(
            "AJAX Request failed. Please try again or contact using email n3olukas@gmail.com."
          );
        },
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("https://images8.alphacoders.com/702/702959.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs a {
  background-color: #f44336;
  width: 33.33%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.125rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 0 .9375rem;
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: #fff;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: #673ab7;
}

table td {
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.ui-state-active a {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.search-results {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1.5625rem 0;
  border-left: 0.3125rem solid #0ebeff;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.search-results h4,
.search-results p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-results a {
  color: #0ebeff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.search-results a:before {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}

.wikisearch-container {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}


/* Screen loader */

#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9.375rem;
  height: 9.375rem;
  margin: -4.6875rem 0 0 -4.6875rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}

#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  right: 0.3125rem;
  bottom: 0.3125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f7d130;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9375rem;
  left: 0.9375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  bottom: 0.9375rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper,
.loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000428;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}


/* Loading animation */


/* Loading animation */

@keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.59375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.lds-eclipse {
  -webkit-animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 0.08rem 0 0 #0ebeff;
}

@media (max-width: 71.875em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 17.96875em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader">
  </div>

  <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="twitchtv-container text-center">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Online</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Offline</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing a foreach loop over the users make a method where you pass a user in.  Once you process that user you snag the next user in the list and call the method again upon completion of the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are techniques for "asynchronous iteration", fetching one user after another is a slow way to make multiple, separate requests. For a situation like this, it is *much* faster to make the fetches in parallel. This is what you're currently doing, but as you've realized the challenge is getting the responses back in the same order as the requests. This is a problem promises solve well (using `Promise.all` and `fetch`). Since you're already using jQuery, you can also accomplish it with jQuery's [Deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```js
var users = [
  "ESL_SC2",
  "OgamingSC2",
  "cretetion",
  "freecodecamp",
  "storbeck",
  "habathcx",
  "RobotCaleb",
  "noobs2ninjas",
  "mhayia"
];

// Transform array of usernames into an array of jQuery deferreds for
// each request. Note that this is actually sending all the requests
// in parallel.
var requests = users.map(function(user) {
  // No need to handle success/failures here, we'll chain those handlers
  // onto the `$.when()` call below.
  return $.ajax({
    url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + user,
    datatype: "json",
    cache: false
  });
});

// Use jQuery.when() to wait for all requests to complete, and provide
// the responses in order (this is the purpose of $.when() or Promise.all()).
// Note that $.when() expects multiple arguments so we need accomodate that
// by spreading our array with Function.prototype.apply(). (This could be
// written more simply in ES2015 as $.when(...requests)).
$.when.apply(null, requests)
  // done() is called after all requests are complete. All responses are
  // passed as arguments in the order the requests were sent.
  .done(function() {
    // Loop through all arguments. Using a `for` loop because built-in
    // `arguments` object isn't a real array, so we can't use
    // arguments.forEach().
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
      var response = arguments[i];
      // Response is an array, the first element is the user object we want.
      var user = response[0];
      console.log(users[i] + " == " + user.display_name);
    }
  })
  // If any request fails, it will be handled here.
  .fail(function() {
    alert('User request failed.');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For the sake of example, here are two network waterfalls recorded with Chrome's dev tools, simulating a "fast 3G" speed. The parallel version is a good 5x faster.

Fetching the users in parallel finishes in 1 second:
[image: Parallel Requests Waterfall]

Fetching the users sequentially takes a good 5 seconds:
[image: Serial Requests Waterfall]

Comment: I think it's even faster, tomorrow I'll take a deep look at this. Thank you!

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis I ran a test of the technique I described compared to a "one request at a time" approach. You can clearly see the huge advantage of parallel requests. I also added a few more comments to the snippet. I kept everything ES5 compatible, but note that there could be a few simplifications made with ES2015 syntax.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use `...request` syntax? I just looked at this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters. And yeah, IE has absolutely no clue what's going on :D

Comment: It's really really faster: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/YeqqNY?editors=0010 :)

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis As you realized, the spread operator isn't supported in all browsers. The code in your original question didn't use any ES2015+ features so I didn't want to assume they were available. That said, you can use a transpiler like Babel to make this code run in all browsers. On CodePen, it's as easy as clicking the settings gear on the JS tab and selecting Babel as your JavaScript preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `forEach` function and loop recursively calling the function `getUserResults()`.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $("html").removeClass("no-js");
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest(),
    users = [
      "ESL_SC2",
      "OgamingSC2",
      "cretetion",
      "freecodecamp",
      "storbeck",
      "habathcx",
      "RobotCaleb",
      "noobs2ninjas",
      "mhayia"
    ],
    index,
    ajaxDone,
    userResults = [],
    $search = $("#search"),
    keyCode,
    request;

  var getUserResults = function(callback, index) {
    //index = 0;
    if (index === users.length) {
      callback();
      return;
    }

    //users.forEach(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + users[index],
      beforeSend: function() {
        ajaxDone = false;
      },
      success: function(d) {
        if (d.display_name !== undefined) {
          userResults[index] = {
            name: d.display_name
          };
          console.log(users[index] + " == " + users[index]);
        }

        getUserResults(callback, ++index);

        //if (index == users.length) {
        //callback();
        //}

        ajaxDone = true;
      },
      error: function() {
        alert(
          "AJAX Request failed. Please try again or contact using email n3olukas@gmail.com."
        );
      },
      datatype: "json",
      cache: false
    });
    //});
  };

  getUserResults(function() {
    index = 0;
    users.forEach(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + e,
        success: function(d) {
          if (d.stream !== null) {
            userResults[index].status = d.stream.channel !== undefined ? 'Online' : '';
            userResults[index].title = d.stream.channel !== undefined ? d.stream.channel.status != undefined ? d.stream.channel.status : '' : '';
            userResults[index].url = d.stream.channel !== undefined ? d.stream.channel.url !== undefined ? d.stream.channel.url : '' : '';
          }

          if (userResults[index].name) {
            $('#tabs-1 table').append('<tr><td>' + userResults[index].name + '</td><td>' + (userResults[index].status ?
              'Online' : 'Offline') + '</td><td>' + (userResults[index].title ?
              userResults[index].title : '') + '</td></tr>');
          }

          index++;

          $("body").addClass("loaded");
        },
        error: function() {
          alert(
            "AJAX Request failed. Please try again or contact using email n3olukas@gmail.com."
          );
        },
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false
      });
    });
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url("https://images8.alphacoders.com/702/702959.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs a {
  background-color: #f44336;
  width: 33.33%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

#search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.125rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 0 .9375rem;
}

.three-dots {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: #fff;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: #673ab7;
}

table td {
  padding: 0.625rem 0;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.ui-state-active a {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.search-results {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 1.5625rem 0;
  border-left: 0.3125rem solid #0ebeff;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.search-results h4,
.search-results p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-results a {
  color: #0ebeff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.search-results a:before {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}

.wikisearch-container {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}


/* Screen loader */

#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9.375rem;
  height: 9.375rem;
  margin: -4.6875rem 0 0 -4.6875rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.75s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}

#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  right: 0.3125rem;
  bottom: 0.3125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f7d130;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9375rem;
  left: 0.9375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  bottom: 0.9375rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.1875rem solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0fff;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+ Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.25s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox  16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper,
.loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000428;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Sadari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: transalteX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+ IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Android 2.1+ Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6 */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+ */
}

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}


/* Loading animation */


/* Loading animation */

@keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes lds-eclipse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.59375rem;
  right: 0.9375rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.lds-eclipse {
  -webkit-animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  animation: lds-eclipse 1s linear infinite;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  box-shadow: 0.08rem 0 0 #0ebeff;
}

@media (max-width: 71.875em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 17.96875em) {
  .wikisearch-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader">
  </div>

  <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="twitchtv-container text-center">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Online</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Offline</a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

See? now the prints are synchronized.